# how to change supergroups in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

```
drwxrwxrwx       - hdfs           supergroup               0   2017-10-23 09:15 /benchmarks
drwxr-xr-x       - cloudera       supergroup               0   2018-05-07 17:31 /data    
drwxr-xr-x        - hbase         supergroup               0   2018-05-14 15:36 /hbase    
drwxr-xr-x         - solr          solr                     0   2017-10-23 09:18 /solr    
drwxrwxrwt        - hdfs           supergroup               0   2018-05-16 18:13 /tmp    
drwxrwxrwx        - hdfs           supergroup               0   2018-04-24 10:32 /user    
drwxr-xr-x        - hdfs           supergroup               0   2017-10-23 09:17 /var
```

how to change `/data` to `hdfs:supergroup`?
how to change `/user` to `cloudera:supergroup`?

Answer (score 1):

To change anything yourself, you need to be a user that has permissions to those files already.

> how to change /data to hdfs:supergroup

```
sudo su - hdfs
hdfs dfs -chown -R hdfs:supergroup /data
```

> how to change /user to cloudera:supergroup

While I would not recommend you overwrite the `/user` properties to anyone but the HDFS superuser...

```
sudo su - hdfs
hdfs dfs -chown -R cloudera:supergroup /user
```